# ctypes passing a pointer to a field in a struct

Tags: python, pointers, struct, ctypes

I need to construct the following data type in Python for passing to a C function:

```
struct {
  unsigned a,b,c;
  char data[8];
};
```

However, I need to actually pass a pointer to the data field to the function, not a pointer to a struct, and I can't figure out how to do this.

Here is what I have so far:

```
from ctypes import *                                                           
class MyStruct(Structure):                                              
  _fields_ = [("a",c_uint), ("b",c_uint), ("c",c_uint), ("data",c_char*8)]
mystruct = MyStruct(0,1,8,"ABCDEFGH")
external_c_function(mystruct.data)
```

Now in C I have this function:

```
int external_c_function(char *data) {
  int a = ((unsigned *)data)[-1];
  int b = ((unsigned *)data)[-2];
  int c = ((unsigned *)data)[-3];
  ...
}
```

The problem is, when the function gets called, "data" correctly points to "ABCDEFGH", but when I try to get the rest of the struct data preceding it, it is garbage.  What am I doing wrong?  Isn't mystruct held sequentially in memory like a real C struct?  I suspect something funny is going on with the array: am I actually doing something silly like this?

```
struct {
  unsigned a,b,c;
  char *data; // -> char[8]
};
```

and if so, how do I do it correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You pass a pointer to an element of a structure by reference, using the offset of the element:

```
external_c_function(byref(mystruct,MyStruct.data.offset))
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that when you reference `mystruct.data`, a copy of the data is made. I say this because the python command `type(mystruct.data)`, returns `str`, rather than a C type.

I presume that you are not able to modify the `external_c_function` to accept the pointer at the start of the structure, as this would be the most obvious solution. Therefore you need to somehow do C style pointer arithmetic in python - i.e. get the address of `mystruct` (possibly using `ctypes.pointer`), then figure out a way to increment this pointer by the appropriate number of bytes.

I don't know how you can do such pointer arithmetic in python, or if it's even possible to do in any robust manner. However, you could always wrap `external_c_function` in another C function which does the necessary pointer arithmetic.

**edit**

Mark's answer solves the problem neatly. My comment about why the error occurs is still correct.